# LINQ query not returning the correct result

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method that gets called on both POST and PUT.  The method updates the current user's username. The query looks like:

```
public override void Save() 
{
    if (SessionManager.CurrentSession.Query<User>()
                                     .Any(u => u.Username == this.Username))
        throw new DuplicateNameException("Username already exists");
    ...
```

This works fine for the POST and every time I try to create a new user with a username that exists in the db, it throws the DuplicateNameException.  On the PUT however, this exception never gets hit when I try to change an existing username to one that already exists.  I have no idea why the query would be different between POST and PUT.  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wait, if you do not change the username, but the user already exists, then won't the `Any` condition return `true`, because the record for the same user matches the filter?

Comment: @JeanHominal So to make sure I understand it correctly, if the current user name is foo@foo.com, then if I do not change the username, and I try the PUT and foo@foo.com gets sent, then does the if statement reign true?  Yes that is the case.  Right now which is not the best UX, they should hit cancel when the modal pops up with their current username and not send in the same username that they already have.

Answer (score 2):

Odd. You have confirmed that the code you expect to be executed IS actually being executed? As in, the PUT call is not resulting in this being skipped or some other method being called instead? And the PUT call IS actually hitting the server? When the PUT call is made, is the "Username" actually being populated correctly? When the PUT call is made, is the "CurrentSession" property and "Query" call actually bound to what they should be and returning the data you expect (e.g. could it be returning an empty list as some connection or other has not been set up in this case)?

Comment: Yes I have actually checked that it gets in this method when PUT gets called, but it skips over the if conditional statement which I was totally confused by.  The username is what I expect, like if the original name was foo@foo.com, and I changed it it to bar@bar.com (assuming bar@bar.com already exists), the if statement returns false.  I need to check on that CurrentSession property and Query like you mentioned.  Some of this ORM stuff is pretty new to me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the username from a form? I'm thinking the username does not get passed properly for the PUT.

Comment: The PUT is not from a form.  We use backbone and on Save, the PUT gets called.  I basically grab the elements using jquery from the input fields, populate my backbone object, and call save().